# Flask Admin - Restrict CRUD functions for own user content

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, crud, flask-admin

I am wondering if there is somebody out there who has successfully restricted the  CRUD functions from flask admin. Or if this is the right tool at all.

What I would like to do is to transform the ModelViews in a way so that a user can only edit the own content. Example: A database table "restaurant menu" contains the dishes offered from different restaurants. If a restaurant wishes to change something, they should be able to change and view their own content but not the content of the other restaurants. Ideally, there is an easy way with sqlalchemy - where I first query a "User" model and get the associated restaurants with the users and then pass it to the ModelView class.

Is there an easy implementation of doing such a thing or are there other CMS system which can handle such a function more easily?

Comment: I've done something similar in my app, parts of it is overriding built-in functions like def get_query(self) and  def get_count_query(self), and many other custom code of course. Even role based seperation is possible when you create more than 1 admin instance.

Comment: Great thanks! Tried it out quickly and overwrote the get_query(self) method. And I can filter the user-specific content for the view by filtering by id. Do you know by any chance as well how I can prepopulate the "edit function" so that a new entry is automatically associated with that user?

Comment: Yes, for instance by overriding with form_args, form_choices, query_factory, etc. Just have a look at Flask-Admin documentation and source code. This all is my custom code I was referring to. If you have specific questions, please share your code and we can help customizing for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went through the source code a bit more deeply. Many thanks to gittert for the help.

Note that within my solution, I do want to restrict the View and Editing function for one particular column, which is also a foreign key from a different table.

So in order to restrict the view functions I did overwrote the get_query() and get_count_query() as it was posted in previous posts:

```
##  overwrite
def get_query(self):
    self._auto_fush_deactivate()
    return super(CustomView, 
self).get_query().filter(User.id== 1)

def get_count_query(self):
    return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(User.id == 1)
```

and to manipulate that the user can only add new data using his OWN foreign key in the table I additionally overwrote the on_model_create() function.

```
def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):

    ### deactivate auto_flush temp. to not receive data integrity error
    self._auto_fush_deactivate()
    ### create model from table user
    overwrite_model = self.session.query(User).filter(User.id== 1).first()

    ### overwrite the user id with model from User-Model
    model.user_id =  overwrite_model
    self._auto_fush_activate()

def _auto_fush_deactivate(self):
    self.session.autoflush = False

def _auto_fush_activate(self):
    self.session.autoflush = True
```